# Capifony failed reinstalling vendors with Symfony2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php, capifony

I'm trying to deploy a **Symfony2.1** project with **Capifony2.1.14** and it failed when reinstalling vendors .

Configuration:
I'm on Mac OSX Montain Lion (client) and have a server on servergrove.com witch is on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

My deploy.rb file looks like this:

```
set :application, "DOA Manager Toshiba"
set :domain,      "root@server.me"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/vhosts/server.me"
set :app_path,    "app"
set :user,        "root"
set :use_sudo,    false

set :repository,  "git://github.com/****/****.git"
set :scm,         :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, or `none`

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Symfony2 migrations will run

set  :keep_releases,  3

set :update_vendors,    true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true


# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
# logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

And here are the output on my terminal:
[image: screenshot of my terminal]

Can someone explain to me why I get this error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add:

```
set :use_composer, true
```

To your deploy.rb.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!

I find the solution by adding the following to my deploy.rb file:
    set :update_vendors,    false
    set :use_composer,     true
    set  :php_bin, "/usr/local/bin/php"
    set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.yml"]

My final deploy.rb which work now fine look like this:

Comment: Note that if you set `:use_composer` to true, `:update_vendors` completely changes in meaning, and should usually be set to false, otherwise you may get versions of vendors that you don't expect. https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues/366